# Using Apache Ignite in singleton mode

Tags: java, ignite

My question is regarding the use case of Apache Ignite in Singleton mode. 
Below is the code that we have written to make it singleton :
TcpDiscoverySpi disco = new TcpDiscoverySpi().setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder(true));

I have the requirement to cache a high volume of data and perform in-memory co-relation. We could have done that by using SQL Joins but that query takes a lot of time so we decided to process this in-memory. 
Is our use-case valid for Apache Ignite ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Ignite stores data in memory and supports SQL operations.

If you have amount of data, that can fit into memory of your machine, then you will get big performance boost comparing to disk-based databases.

And even if you have more data, than memory available, you can still use Ignite by configuring [native persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store). This way all data will be stored on disk, but the hottest part will be kept in memory.